# jquery Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following code. I am trying to animate the png so it appears to stretch. however when the code runs, I receive the error: 
Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.

Jquery is initialized on the document, as it is used in other functions.

Any help would be much appreciated

```js
$("#light-switch")[0].animate(
    {height: "30%"} ,500, function(){
      console.log("moved")
 });
```

```css
#light-switch{
   z-index: 5;
   width: 10%;
   height: 25%;
   position: absolute;
   top:63%;
   right:20%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="clickable" id="light-switch-link" >
      <img id="light-switch" src="./images/switch-on.png" alt="light_switch"  />
</div>
<!-- Scripts for bootstraps -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="./js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching in the index of $("#light-switch")[0] which is wrong. You don't need to define it. This will straightly work $("#light-switch").animate(.

This will work for you.

```js
$("#light-switch").animate(
    {height: "30%"} ,500, function(){
      console.log("moved")
 });
```

```css
#light-switch{
   z-index: 5;
   width: 10%;
   height: 25%;
   position: absolute;
   top:63%;
   right:20%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="clickable" id="light-switch-link" >
      <img id="light-switch" src="./images/switch-on.png" alt="light_switch"  />
</div>
<!-- Scripts for bootstraps -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="./js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```